# Best way to return data from multiple columns into one row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with just order numbers and another with order numbers and all of the data associated with those order numbers. I want to match the order numbers and transfer all of the available data into the other sheet. I've been trying to use loops and VLOOKUP but I'm having problems (plus I have 116 columns I want to transfer data from so my vlookup expression doesn't look very nice). Any advice would be appreciated!

this is what I have so far and I'm getting an object error.
I don't think it's the right way to go about it in general though.

```
Dim LookUpRange As Range
Dim row As Range
Set LookUpRange = Worksheets("batches").Range("B4:B1384")
Set row = Worksheets("batches").Range("C:DL")
    For Each row In LookUpRange
      row.Select
      Selection.FormulaArray ="=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],OrderLvl!RC[-1]:R[1380]C[113],{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,207,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115},FALSE)"
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: At a very high view my suggestion would be to rather loop through the order number column, with each value do a `Set FoundRow = LookUpRange.Find(what:row.value2...` and then make the columns to the right of your search term equal to  `LookUpRange.Rows(FoundRow.Row).Value2` or something to that effect. Hope this guides you in the right direction. Cheers

Comment: The `Set row = Worksheets("batches").Range("C:DL")` line isn't achieving anything because the very next line re-uses the row variable to iterate through the LookupRange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this VBA script to resolve your inquiry:

```
Sub LookupOuput()

    Dim OrderNumberColumn As Range
    Set OrderNumberColumn = Worksheets("batches").Range("B2:B1384")

    Dim LookUpRange As Range
    Set LookUpRange = Worksheets("OrderLvl").Range("C:DL")

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FindResult As Range

    For Each cell In OrderNumberColumn

        If Not cell.Value2 = Empty Then

            Set FindResult = LookUpRange.Find(what:=cell.Value2)

            If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
                cell.Range("A1:DJ1").Value2 = LookUpRange.Rows(FindResult.row).Value2
            End If

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Basically searches for each Order Number in the first sheet on the second sheet. This outputs (if search term exists) the cell that that string is found which we later refer to its row number to output the whole row to the first sheet. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

A regular `VLOOKUP` may be able to give you what you need, if you use a small trick...

1. Insert a row above the data table, and put sequential numbers in
   each cell of that row. (ie, A1 = 1, B1 = 2, C1 = 3, etc...)
2. Do the same thing on your blank table.
3. Assuming that your first order number is in cell A2, put the following formula into B2: `=VLOOKUP($A2,[other sheet name]!$A$1:$DZ$5000,B$1,0)`
4. Drag this formula across all 116 columns, then down all however many rows you've got.

You'll need to adjust the ranges, obviously, but make sure that your lookup array starts in column A. (or alternatively, that your numbers start in the same column as the first column in your array.) Adding the numbers along the top allows you to change what column of the array you're referencing, just by dragging the cell formula.